# My question is how can i install flash player without changing the admin password

Tags: flash

I am using an ubuntu machine in my office. And i am logged in as a normal user.I dont have the admin password.
I know how to change the password of the admin user. However, if i do that it will create a problem. So without affecting the old password i want to install the flash player. 
Request to experts please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your account is part of the `sudoers` group and allowed to switch to the root user account you might be able to get root permissions with `sudo su -`without having to know or enter the root account's password.